# difficult constraint for a mysql-table

Tags: mysql, join, constraints

I need a constraint for a mysql-table. The table has the fields 'id', 'ref', 'from' and 'to'. The constraint schould guarantee that there are no datasets with the same 'ref' and a time overlapping (fields 'from' and 'to').

In sql: The following statement should always return '0'.

```
select count(*) 
from   `TABLE` d1 inner join `TABLE` d2 on 
       d1.`ref` = d2.`ref` and d1.`id` <> d2.`id` and 
       d1.`to` >= d2.`from` and d1.`from`<=d2.`to`
```

Is there a way to handle this with constrains?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I think you need a trigger to handle something like this.

Comment: MySQL constraints check only for existance, not for value range. It's easy with a trigger though.

Comment: then the trigger has to stop the execution (before insert or update) and maybe throw an exception, is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Run unknown procedure from the trigger - CALL sp1(), or use SIGNAL statement on MySQL 5.5

Answer (score 0):

Now I have the following triggers. Thanks for your help!

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `devtestplandb`$$

CREATE
TRIGGER `db`.`trig1`
BEFORE INSERT ON `db`.`TABLE`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET @CNT = (
            select  count(*) 
            from    `TABLE` d 
            where   d.`ref` = NEW.`ref` and 
                    d.`to` >= NEW.`from` and 
                    d.`from` <= NEW.`to`);
    IF @CNT != 0 THEN
        CALL error_001();
    END IF;
END$$

CREATE
TRIGGER `db`.`trig2`
BEFORE UPDATE ON `db`.`TABLE`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET @CNT = (
            select  count(*) 
            from    `TABLE` d 
            where   d.`ref` = NEW.`ref` and 
                    d.`ID` <> NEW.`ID` and
                    d.`to` >= NEW.`from` and 
                    d.`from` <= NEW.`to`);
    IF @CNT != 0 THEN
        CALL error_002();
    END IF;
END$$
```

Answer (score 0):

*"Is there a way to handle this with constrains?"*

Yes, SQL Standard 2011 supports this kind of scenarios in readable declarative manner:

> [unique constraint definition](https://jakewheat.github.io/sql-overview/sql-2011-foundation-grammar.html#_11_7_unique_constraint_definition)

> ```
> <without overlap specification> ::=
> <application time period name>  WITHOUT OVERLAPS
> ```

In your example:

```
CREATE TABLE tab (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  ref VARCHAR(100),
  from_date DATE,
  end_date DATE,
  PERIOD FOR ref_period(from_date, end_date),
  UNIQUE (ref, ref_period WITHOUT OVERLAPS)
);
```

And sample inserts:

```
INSERT INTO tab(ref, from_date, end_date) VALUES ('a', '2020-01-01','2020-03-01');
-- OK

INSERT INTO tab(ref, from_date, end_date) VALUES ('a', '2020-03-01','2020-05-01');
-- OK

INSERT INTO tab(ref, from_date, end_date) VALUES ('a', '2020-04-01','2020-07-01')
-- Duplicate entry 'a-2020-07-01-2020-04-01' for key 'ref

SELECT * FROM tab;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo - Maria DB 10.5](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=437f1b5fb12b0cfdb1a01c0653e7ebee)**